# @QuarkusMain not executed in @QuarkusTest

Tags: quarkus

We are using a custom main class with @QuarkusMain annotation. This does not seem to be called when @QuarkusTest annotation is used to run tests. The problem is that we are then missing some common initialization in the tests (timezone, camel integration etc.)

When we uncomment @QuarkusMain and rely on the auto-generated main class which quarkus provides by default, the whole context (including camel) is initialized properly and works out of the box, but obviously we are now missing our customizations.

Is there any way to run @QuarkusTests with @QuarkusMain? Is it not working by design or would this be a bug?

Quarkus version: 2.1.3.Final, quarkus-junit5

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you open an issue so we can investigate? Thanks

Comment: @geoand issue created under https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19957 with a small reproducer.